# Redirect on workflow execution

Tags: workflow

I have a site workflow (on a sub-site) that I am starting from a link on the main site.  Works fine, except when the workflow completes it redirects me to sub-site's workflow page.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing that, preferably with control of where I am redirected to?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question? If so, could you post it below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try altering (or appending) the `Source=` query string parameter to the link that starts your workflow. SharePoint is designed to "return" to whatever URL value you place in this parameter.